# Identify a math script font

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Today I saw an amsart article with the following script "I" in it:

[image: script I]

But I can't identify which font it is. All math script fonts I know are `\mathcal`, `\mathscr`, and `\mathfrak`, but none of these match. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: This is `$\Im$`, which is in the standard fonts.

Comment: @egreg Oh yeah, I didn't know imaginary part has its own command. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg No problem.